# How do Conditions in Java know which Thread to trigger?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

I am reading the [Condition Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) from Java and I have a misunderstanding. Reading their example of `put` and `take`, as you see they have in the function `put` the line of code: `notEmpty.signal()` where `notEmpty` is a Condition from `lock`.

What I am wondering if what if there are **multiple** threads that are waiting for the signal of `notEmpty`. What happens in this case and which thread is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

It make a system call to the OS which handles it. The JVM has no idea which thread if any will wake.

Threads are managed by the OS not the JVM so the best it can do is make the right system calls and let the OS do the rest.

Comment: So in a real implementation then, if we have this code with `signal` and `await` it is a crapshoot as to which threads will get triggered with `signal` so I guess this approach only works for two threads in total? Thanks

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia Unless you use a more expensive "fair" lock, the order is random, Note `await` can wake spuriously.

Comment: Ok, and one more question.From that documentation code sample, Suppose a thread `Produce` calls `put` and so `Produce` is now owning the lock `lock`. But the `while` condition is true so Produce does `notFull.await()`. My question is now if a thread `Consume` calls take, at the line which says `lock.lock()` what exactly happens?

I am kind of confused because we let the old lock go in the critical section and now need to acquire it from a different thread.

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia not sure what you mean but calling await releases the lock until it wakes up and re-acquires it.

Comment: I have a doubt here -- once I call `cond.await()` and someone calls `cond.signal()`, then this `cond.await()` will understand that then it return `return` and then check the condition again for the `while` loop. What I am wondering is, this `await()` only returns AFTER I have reqaquired the `lock` right?

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia even if await returns spuriously, it will be get the lock first which means if another thread holds the lock it will appear to be stuck on await if you take a stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I think the thread calls *await()* first will be triggered first , and the conclusion comes from the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java).

What did *await()* do ?

1. create a wait node and add the node to a fifo queue maintained by *Condition*
2. release the lock, you see before you call *await()*,you need to call *lock.lock()*
3. test if *signal()* was called during step 2 by other thread. if no then park current thread.

What did *signal()* do ?

- take a node in the queue maintained by *Condition* and put it in the queue maintained by *Lock*, so if one thread call *await()* first , it will get into *Lock's* queue first

When will the parked thread be awaken ?

Apparently,*Lock.unlock()* will be called after *Condition.signal()*, *Lock.unlock()* will get one node in *Lock's* waiting queue from the head to the tail, see *AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#unparkSuccessor*,so if you enter *Lock's* queue first, you will be triggered first.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wondering is, what if there are multiple threads that are waiting for the signal of notEmpty. What happens in this case and which thread is triggered?

As others have already answered, you can not know which thread will be triggered.

> so I guess this approach only works for two threads in total?

Depends what "this approach" means. It often *does* make sense to have several threads awaiting the same condition.  The trick is, since you can not know which thread will be awakened, you should write your code in such a way that it does not *matter* which thread is awakened.

This is an example of a good practice that you should try to follow when you write multi-threaded code, namely: When there's work to be done, it should not matter which thread does the work.

Comment: Could not agree more:)